# Control View size in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I want to create an `AlertDialog` as a `DialogFragment` with a title, an ok button, a cancel button and an `ExpandableListView`. The problem is that the `ExpandableListView` takes as much space as it likes and pushes the buttons and the title out of the dialog. What I want is the title at the top, the buttons at the bottom and the `ExpandableListView` to take all the rest of the space, up to fullscreen, so that the `DialogFragment` does not increase/decrease in size when expanding it, but rather keep it scrollable.

Here is an image describing the situation, the left one is the initialized `DialogFragment`, the second is after expanding one of the sections of the `ExpandableListView`. Nevermind the ugliness.

[image: ExpandableListView expands too much.]

I would like to achieve the following:

1. Keep the size of the `FragmentDialog` fixed, preferably to the whole window (`fill_parent`/`match_parent`).
2. Keep the buttons fixed at the bottom, the title fixed at the top and the `ExpandableListView` fixed (but still scrollable) in the center.

I have tried lots of various things, but here is my current take.

**The custom DialogFragment**

```
public class RecipeFilterDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.recipe_filter_title);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.recipe_filter_button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO: Perform filtering, fill list and return.
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.recipe_filter_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO: Kill dialog and return.
            }
        });

        builder.setView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.recipe_filter_dialog, null));
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
        if (dialog != null)
        {
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            //dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
            dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

**The xml file for the DialogFragment (recipe_filter_dialog.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.my.app.RecipeFilterExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_filter_expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The custom ExpandableListView**

```
public class RecipeFilterExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

    public RecipeFilterExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOnGroupExpandListener(new RecipeFilterDialogOnGroupExpandListener(this));

        // This adapter just fills the ExpandableListView, nevermind it.
        this.setAdapter(new RecipeFilterExpandableListAdapter(context, ((MyActivity)context).getDbFilter()));
    }
}
```

Comment: give a fixed layout height and width to the view

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `builder.setTitle(R.string.recipe_filter_title);` instead of  `builder.setMessage(R.string.recipe_filter_title);` and decide what height and width you want for your `Dialog` and set it in `onStart()` method.

Also try to do something like this:

Constructor in your dialog class:

```
 public RecipeFilterDialogFragment () {
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.FullscreenStyle);
    }
```

and style for this dialog that is used above:

```
<style name="FullscreenStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

also try to use parent style as a dialog theme f.e:

```
<style name="FullscreenStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
```

Comment: The styling did seemingly not affect the size of the dialog, but using `setTitle` did change some minor things (just visual). How do you suggest I calculate and set the height of the dialog in `onStart()`? I cannot really find the means to do it, and I guess it is required for both the dialog and the `RecipeFilterExpandableListView` inside it. Oh, and setting `android:layout_height="300dp"` in the xml file for the `RecipeFilterExpandableListView` does give the desired behavior, but does not really help since it is hard coded.

Comment: If you really want to create fullscreen dialog just calculate width and height by device screen size. [Get screen dimensions in pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/4675547) and then the style will affect the size of the dialog. I hope this will help.